# Why WPF localization falls back for some assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We have a WPF based application which we are trying to localize. We are using the locbaml method where we generate satellite assemblies containing resources (.baml files). For each language we have 5 different resource assemblies because there are translatable resources in multiple assemblies the application uses.

The problem is that upon setting a different language as UI culture and by looking at the Output window in Visual Studio as the application starts up, we noticed that of the 5 satellite assemblies 4 are loaded correctly from the language sub-folder we just set but for one of them the application falls back and loads the one from the neutral culture sub-folder (which is "en" in our case). We are using the same method to generate all the satellites, so we have no clue of why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: We found the answer ourselves, the problem is that the localized satellite was not signed with the same .snk (strong name key) file as the original (neutral culture) satellite was, and this was happening only for one of the assemblies.

Comment: Usually you can see the reason for failure in the fusion log; you would need however to break on thrown exception (`AssemblyLoadException`? can't remember).